# How do you search through a hash mapped from an ActiveRecord result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a hash variable that contains the results from an ActiveRecord search, which will be iterated through to display data. My code (transcribed) goes somewhere like this:

```
 hvar=User.map{|x| {:name => x.name, :type => x.type, :section => x.section, 
       :result => (x.var1/x.var2).round(1)}}
```

The hash variable 'hvar' would then display the following through an .inspect :

```
 [
    {:name=>'Michael', :type=>7, :section=>1, :result=>4.1},
    {:name=>'Seymour', :type=>4, :section=>1, :result=>3.9},
    {:name=>'Walter', :type=>2, :section=>1, :result=>6.3},
    {:name=>'Josephine', :type=>7, :section=>1, :result=>5.4},
    {:name=>'Carla', :type=>7, :section=>0, :result=>5.4}
 ]
```

So far, so good.

Now, I wish to do a search through that resulting hash, e.g. all those records of type 7, and I'm not sure how to get to it. I found that you could do something like this:

```
mission=hvar.select{|k| k[:type] == 7}
```

But it gives me 0 results, which makes sense to me, as I think it is searching through the "first level" of the hash (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3) instead of the subhashes within.

How could I find all those records with type 7? And to that effect, how could I also do a search on two fields? Say, type == 7 and section == 1.

In case you're wondering, I'm not doing the search from the ActiveRecord itself, cause I have to iterate through every single record and arrange them in a pivoted table that merges this data with another table. So, to make it more efficient I figured to use a hash instead of iterating through the ActiveRecord, which currently it's spitting somewhere around 1700 SQL queries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is working as written. You've done everything correctly. If you have a problem, it isn't reproduced by the code you've posted. There is no "first level" here, there is an array, and it contains hashes. Your `select` statement is written exactly right: http://pastebin.com/avFcLKE1

Comment: You're right. Guess I'm overlooking something else, cause I keep getting 0 results. I went through this several times, and I even manually typed a code very similar to this and I got nothing. But, indeed, I went and wrote this and it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is written correctly. The only thing that can really be answered is

> how could I also do a search on two fields? Say, type == 7 and section == 1.

The same way you're doing so now, plus an additional condition:

```
mission = hvar.select { |k| k[:type] == 7 && k[:section] == 1}
```

Comment: Turns out I was mixing variables, which resulted on 0 results. However, I also needed to include a second (and third) argument, so this has been really helpful. Thanks!